# grafana define variable with prometheus query based on metrics

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am pretty new to Grafana, so the question might be an easy one:

I try to store a metric value in a variable. Therefore I setup a variable with Prometheus query:

> `metrics(passed_tests_total{job="MyJob"})`

Surprising to me, the value returns value `None`, although metric values with that label exist. I verified that by setting up a 'singlestat' panel with query `passed_tests_total{job="MyJob"}` which works perfectly fine.

So my question: how can I store a metric value to a variable?

Remark: my approach is basing on docu http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the value of a metric you should use `query_result()`, `metrics()` gives you the *name* of matching metrics, not the value itself.

Your Query should be: `query_result(passed_tests_total{job="MyJob"})`

And the Regex to extract just the value of metric should be `/.* ([^\ ]*) .*/`.

Comment: Ah, got it. Looks quite obvious :-) .

Comment: Remark: was not clear to me from documentation, that `metrics` gives the *names*. In the documentation  http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/ it is written: "Returns a list of metrics matching the specified metric regex."

Comment: @CarloGiorgetta not sure if you're interested in making an open-source contribution, but clarifying the docs here sounds like a good candidate to me. (Forgive me if this is condescending - some people are looking for "easy first issues" to become OSS contributors)